# filter fields of type date with the view module filters

Tags: views

I have a field in my database of type: timestamp in this format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss , with the view module I would like to filter this field so for example I want to select an interval: dispaly only date from x to y. I taked a look in the view module code and there is a date filter that handel data of type date or time in this format, but when I tired to create a new view with view module and set up this kind of filter I didnt found it in the exposed filter list, the availble filters works only with int or string type: like is equal to, starts with...so how to get the time filter from the view module user interface.

Comment: Do you have the Date module installed? https://drupal.org/project/date

Comment: yes but I still dont have the date filter in my view module interface

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the **Date Views** module (part of the [Date](https://drupal.org/project/date) project) to be able to filter using interval operators such as "Is between":

[image]

Take a look at the upvoted answer to this question for details: [How do I add a date field that can be filtered by a relative value?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95662/how-do-i-add-a-date-field-that-can-be-filtered-by-a-relative-value)

Comment: yes Thank you I have already tried this: the use of the date module and I have obtained those filters in my view module interface but the problem once I apply one filter for example filter date between date1 and date 2 I obtain nothing as a result!

Comment: yes just after publishing the question I tried to use the Date module